# Symfony Deployment : wrong url on login

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I've just put my symfony folder on my (test local) production environnement.

I have cleared my dev and prod cache but there is an issue when I log in.

Here is my url to login :

> http://192.168.0.250/cao-symfony/web/login

and here is the url I get when I'm redirected on logon

> http://192.168.0.250**/cao-symfony/web**/cao-symfony/web/abonnements

whereas I expect something more like

> http://192.168.0.250/cao-symfony/web/abonnements

On my login form I've put this property :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ path('listeAbo-page') }}" />
```

Which is binded to this route :

```
/**
* @Route("/abonnements", name="listeAbo-page")
*/
```

What I am wondering is where does the duplicate "/cao-symfony/web" on my url come from ? apache configuration or symfony redirect rules.

```
<Directory "/var/www/cao-symfony">
            DirectoryIndex app.php
            Options -Indexes
            AllowOverride All
            Allow from All
</Directory>
```

On my apache conf should I put something else like /var/www/cao-symfony/web/ ?

EDIT : The only redirect on my project is this one :

```
root:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /abonnements
        permanent: true
```

in my routing.yml

I have several website on the /var/www/ folder.

Thank you.

Comment: What happens after you're logged in? Do you redirect the user to that page, or is it some bundle that handles the login and requires the `_target_path`-field to exist in your form? If you're redirecting manually, you should use something like `$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('listeAbo-page'));`. In other cases, check if the generated path starts with a `/`, otherwise it might be treated relatively in stead of absolute.

Comment: As you can see, I'm using _target_path without manually redirect.
The only redirect on my project is this one :

root:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /abonnements
        permanent: true

in my routing.yml

Comment: You have a function called `urlRedirect` in that controller, what does it do?
Does this url even show a valid page? `http://192.168.0.250/cao-symfony/web/cao-symfony/web/abonnements`. Check what the `console router:debug` command shows.

Comment: Ok, so that `urlRedirect` comes from Sysmfony; didn't know that. I think it generates a url for `/abonnements`, which results in `cao-symfony/web/abonnements`. Because you're already in `/cao-symfony/web`, I guess the generated url is appended to the current one, resulting in `/cao-symfony/web/cao-symfony/web/abonnements`. Can't think of anything else. Try doing it manually in one of your controllers, see if that works out. Still curious about the `router:debug`, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i get from my router:debug :

```
listeAbo-page                       ANY    ANY    ANY  /abonnements
```

Seems OK for me.

From @ar34z, i've tested to put the URL directly on my login form (/abonnements) and it works. It's the only link in the whole site which have a problem. I still doesn't understand why.

Thank you all of you to brought me your help.

Comment: Be careful with this kind of dev environment. You can easily write bad links or mistake an url that is working with your custom url and not in a production environment (which the URI should starts after `/`) .

Comment: thank you, but what kind of test I could do, to investigate the issue?
my debug:router show something fine. Seems to me that symfony do something wrong with the _target_path input.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from your base url.

In a production environement, the URI of your symfony routes should begin just after your host.

For example, your `/abonnements` route should be accessible by browsing `http://192.168.0.250/abonnements`

To do that, make your virtual host like this :

```
<Directory "/var/www/cao-symfony/web/">
    DirectoryIndex app.php
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

And browse your application at `http://192.168.0.250/` directly.

For more informations, see the [Configuring a web server](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html) part of the documentation.

**Update**

If you doesn't want use `/` of your ip, make a virtual host :

```
// yourdomain.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourdomain.dev
    <Directory "/var/www/cao-symfony/web/">
        DirectoryIndex app.php
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Enable it :

```
a2ensite yourdomain.conf
```

And use it by browsing `http://yourdomain.dev` .

Comment: there is multiple other website on my apache. So i cannot use / as the root directory.
I've try to add /web/ at the end part : nothing change.
Allways the same duplicate url